# How to turn off flashing notification LED on HTC Sensation XE?

Tags: settings, htc-sense

Two problems:

1. The LED flashes green every now and then. I disabled all options in Setting-Display-Notification flash, but it just keeps on flashing now and then. How can I completely turn it off?
2. The LED flashes red when the battery is low. How can I disable this, too?

Thanks in advance! I ask this because I often read ebook on my phone, it's annoying to have the light flash.

Comment: did u ever find out a solution?

Comment: @Jorge I gave up.